# How do I select token value using com.datastax.oss.driver.api.querybuilder.QueryBuilder?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

How to rewrite

```sql
select  token(id) as t, id  from example
```

using  `com.datastax.oss.driver.api.querybuilder.QueryBuilder` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOKEN()` is a native CQL function which you cannot call with the `QueryBuilder`. It also doesn't make sense to do so.

If you already have a static CQL query, you should just execute it. The general proposition for the Query builder in the Java driver is to generate dynamic CQL queries. It isn't a replacement for static statements. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do as described in [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/query_builder/select/#functions), something like this:

```java
selectFrom("example").function("token", Selector.column("id")).column("id");
```